# gulpでtraceurでコンパイルしたjsとbowerのjsを共存させるには

Tags: gulp

gulpでtraceurでコンパイルしたes6のjsと、bowerでinstallしたのjsを、concatしてminifyしてsourcemapを正しく設定したいですのですが、gulpfile.jsをどのように設定すればいいでしょうか。

```
project_root
├── bower.json
├── bower_components
│   ├── traceur-runtime
│   ├── いろいろ
├── dist
│   ├── all.js
│   └── index.html
├── gulpfile.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── いろいろ
├── package.json
└── src
    ├── es6
    │   └── main.js.es6
    └── index.slim
```